# PHP watch a variable?

Tags: php

I am wondering if there is a way to watch for variable changes in PHP. For example let's say I have a class

```
class Chicken
{
    public $test = "hi";
}

$test = new Chicken();
$test->test = "hello"; // I want to know when this happens
```

Is there anyways to determine if a variable was changed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make this a private variable and then use the [`__set()` magic method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set) to filter all member variable value changes.

```
class Chicken
{
    private $test = "hi";

    public function __set($name, $value) {
      echo "Set:$name to $value";
      $this->$name = $value;
    }

    public function getTest() {
      return $this->test;
    }

    // Alternative to creating getters for all private members
    public function __get($name) {
      if (isset($this->$name)) {
        return $this->$name;
      }
      return false;
    }
}

$test = new Chicken();
$test->test = "hello"; // prints: Set: test to hello
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.org/9LapODW9)

Comment: How could I then get it?

Comment: That's pretty clever.  `__set` runs for "inaccessible properties", and since it's "inaccessible" outside the class, it works ^~^

Comment: @JohnConde: Couldn't you also use `__get()`?

Comment: @RocketHazmat Yes, you can :)